# TextBox strings to multiple rows

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a an ActiveX Multi-Line TextBox1 embedded in a Work Sheet. It has values (separated by line breaks/carriage returns) that I'm trying to get into multiple cells (A1:A5 in this case, but however many I need depending on however many lines the user enters in TextBox1), but so far I've only been able to get them into one cell (in this case, A1). I've tried setting the LinkedCell to multiple ranges in the Properties of TextBox1, but this doesn't work.

---

```
 What I've got:                                            TextBox1
                                                              |

             A   
                                                  ------------------------------
 1            a                                  |a                             |
              b                                  |b                             |
              c                                  |c                             |
              d                                  |d                             |
              e                                  |e                             |
                                                  ------------------------------

 ------------------------------------------------------------------

 What I'm trying to get:

                                                           TextBox1
                                                              |

             A   
                                                -------------------------------
 1           a                                  |a                             |
 2           b                                  |b                             |
 3           c                                  |c                             |
 4           d                                  |d                             |
 5           e                                  |e                             |
                                                --------------------------------

 -----------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to output the value/strings separated by breaks/carriage returns of TextBox1 into multiple cells? Thanks!

---

Here is a macro that I've recently tried:

```
Sub TextBoxToRow() 
  Dim Arr As Variant 

  Arr = Split(ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text, vbLf) 
  Range("B2").Resize(, UBound(Arr) + 1) = Arr 
End Sub
```

where the value is grabbed from the textbox and use the carriage return as a delimiter. But no go

I think the problem is that the macro simply may not be launching when I enter the strings into the textbox (which is what I meant when I said "no go"...simply that nothing happens).

Comment: You can link only one cell to any control. After you need a macro to further process your data.

Comment: Thanks very much Máté. Here is a macro that I've recently tried:                                   Sub TextBoxToRow()
  Dim Arr As Variant
  Arr = Split(ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text, vbLf)
  Range("B2").Resize(, UBound(Arr) + 1) = Arr
End Sub: where the value is grabbed from the textbox and use the carriage return as a delimiter. But no go.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you've tried! Please also edit your question and include your code. What "no go" exactly means? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Hi Máté, sorry I wasn't more clear. I attached the macro above to my textbox (TextBox1). I think the problem is that the macro simply may not be launching when I enter the strings into the textbox (which is what I meant when I said "no go"...simply that nothing happens. :) What I'm trying to do by this macro is to get the value (the strings) that I enter into the textbox (ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text...I've also tried to change this and use TextBox1.Value but still nothing happens) and split them. I've also been trying to Split them into an array and transposing them into column ("no go" yet).

Answer (score 0):

The key here, is to use the change event of your textbox, so whenever you change anything your macro will run.

Easiest way to insert it is to go to the code module of your worksheet containing the textbox, open dropdown at top left corner and select the name of your textbox, it'll automatically insert sub for change event.

I also needed to slightly modify your code to work:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Target As Range

    Arr = Split(ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Text, vbLf)
    Set Target = Range("B2")
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Target.Value = Arr(i)
        Set Target = Target.Offset(1, 0)
    Next i
End Sub
```

If you don't want each change to be reflected, just once you leave textbox, then you can use LostFocus event instead of Change.